# How to encrypt columns in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, encryption, postgresql-9.1

I'm new to PostgreSQL and never worked with encryption. I read some links about encryption in PostgreSQL, like [this one](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgcrypto.html), but I'm a little bit confused about what it wants to say (or what I understand:)). Can you guide me with some thoughts or links in this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not buy a book about encryption first? I've downvoted this message for the simple reason that it is way too open.

Answer (score 8):

Look into the pgcrypto addon.  Note that db-level cryptography is tricky.  You have key management issues that are not trivial to resolve.  In general if you really need this, it is probably worth hiring a professional consultant to do some code review and another one to provide some design review ahead of time.

In general, I don't recommend doing all your encryption in the db at present unless it is required due to regulatory or similar regimes.

Answer (score -6):

You can encrypt data by using md5 ex like `md5(your colunn name)`

Comment: MD5 is not encryption. It's a hashing function, and a poor one by today's standards.